# Set up SSH on vps

Tags: ssh

I've basically locked myself out of my vps. There's nothing on it, so there's not too much worry, but I really want to know how to fix the problem.

I've locked myself out by disabling root access, and then overwriting id_rsa. I've learned my lesson, and will be naming all my key pairs from now on.

Anyway, whenever I attempt to logon via ssh

```
ssh username@xxx -p 2222
```

I get this:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
d
Received disconnect from xxxxx: 2: Too many authentication failures for root
```

The problem is I no longer have a valid key, so my ssh agent offers each one in turn, until the server ignores me.

I can easily generate another key pair locally, but I'm confused as to what to do on the server side of things?

I have root access via a cloud console.

Answer (score 1):

If you can paste text into your console, you can paste the public key of the new keypair into the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of your VPS.

SSH keys are asymmetric public/private keys, so you only need the public key to be on the machine you're connecting **to**. The private key stays on the machine you're connecting **from**.

To view your newly-generated keypair's public key, you can `cat` the id_rsa.pub file that should be created automatically (that is if you use the `ssh-keygen` command to generate your new keypair).